# How to decide if $X^2 +1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_{9}[X]$ and reduce $X^{6}+X^{4}+X^{2}+1$ in $\mathbb{F}_{9}[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I know that $\mathbb{F}_9[X]$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}[i])[X]$

I know know that because f is of degree two, that f is reducibel iff f has zero's in $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}[i]$. I could just fill in my 9 elements, but how should i solve this problem if i had a much larger ring? Is there a method to see whether elements can be a root or not before filling them into your polynomial?

furthermore i don't understand how to reduce $X^{6}+X^{4}+X^{2}+1$ in $\mathbb{F}_{9}[X]$.

i thought about reducing $X^{9}-X$ in irreducible monical polynomials of degree 1 and then try out combinations to find my f, but that seemed quite hard. So i wandered if i'm missing out on a few usefull theorems...?

Comment: $\{a+bi \space \text{with}\space a,b\in\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}\}$

Comment: but $\mathbb{F}_{9}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_3[i]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}[i]$. and so i thought that if we have $A$ isomorphic with $B$ that then $A[X]$ isomorphic to $B[X]$. Or is this utter nonsense....?

Comment: @user ... isn't $x^2 + 1$ irreducible over ${\mathbb F}_3$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write $$X^6 + X^4 + X^2 + 1 = \frac{X^8 - 1}{X^2 - 1} $$

Next note that $X^8 - 1$ splits over ${\mathbb F}_9$, and a as a hint for this part, I am going to leave here a more general result which is good to know:

**Result** Let $F$ be a finite field, then over it we have:

$$ \prod_{g\in F} (X - g) = X^{|F|} - X $$

In your case, this is $X^9 - X = X (X^8 - 1)$.

As for $X^2 + 1$, it is interesting to note that, if $\alpha$ is a generator of ${\mathbb F}_9^\times$, then $\pm \alpha^2$ are roots of it (Why?).

Comment: yes i heard this argument before, but then $\alpha^8 = 1$ because we know our ring is cyclical. But then $\alpha^4 = ±1$ but when we fill these in as roots we get $X^{2}-1$ so it must be $\alpha^2$.

Comment: @KeesTil I am not sure I understand what you meant there in the end. $\alpha^4$ can't be $1$, right?, so, since as you said $\alpha^4$ is either $1$ or $-1$...

Comment: but why can't it be 1? $(\alpha^{4})^{2} = 1$ implies $\alpha^{4} = +-1$ right? Or is the argument that if $\alpha^{4} = 1$ that our cyclical group is of order 4?

Comment: @KeesTil Exactly as you said in the end. The multiplicative groups of finite fields are cyclic, hence, if $\alpha$ is a generator of $F^\times$, it has order $|F|-1$. In this case, it has order $8$, so it can't be that $\alpha^4 = 1$, else it would have order $\leq 4$. Note in general that if $|F| - 1$ is even, then any generator must satisfy $\alpha^{\frac{|F|-1}{2}} = -1$. That was a remark on how to find solutions, in this case, you could say that $X^2 + 1$ is a divisor of $X^8 - 1$ too, and use the above result.

Answer (score 1):

$-1$ *is* a square in $\mathbb{F}_9$, because $X^2+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_3$, so $\mathbb{F}_9$ is the splitting field of $X^2+1$ (or of any other degree two irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_3$).

Then $X^6+X^4+X^2+1=X^4(X^2+1)+(X^2+1)=(X^4+1)(X^2+1)$, so you're reduced to factorize $X^4+1=X^4-2X^2+1-X^2=(X^2-1)^2-X^2=(X^2-X-1)(X^2+X+1)$. Each of the factors is reducible in $\mathbb{F}_9$ because of the above considerations. Just find their roots.

Comment: I got a hint that says: (look at $X^9 - X$). Do you understand how this hint is constructive?

Comment: @KeesTil $X^9-X=X(X^4+1)(X^4-1)=X(X-1)(X+1)(X^2+1)(X^4+1)$; each of those factors is completely reducible over $\mathbb{F}_9$, because the polynomial has nine distinct roots. Just find them: you can represent elements of $\mathbb{F}_9$ as $a+bi$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{F}_3$ and $i^2=-1=2$. Of course you know the roots of $X$, $X+1$, $X-1$ and $X^2+1$, so what are the roots of $X^4+1$?

Comment: this one is actually quite hard, but i got 1+i and 1-i. :)

Comment: @KeesTil $0$, $1$, $2=-1$, $i$, $2i=-i$ are already covered; so $1+i$, $1+2i=1-i$, $2+i$ and $2+2i$ are the roots of $X^4+1$.

Comment: of course that are all nine elements that was quite stupid hahahaha

Answer (score 0):

For the second question, note that 
$$
x^6+x^4+x^2+1=x^4(x^2+1)+(x^2+1)=(x^4+1)(x^2+1)=(x^2+2x+2)(x^2+x+2)(x^2+1)
$$
over any field of characteristic $p=3$.